# What does the summary output of the coding with ffmpeg means

Tags: java, video, ffmpeg

I am working with video comparison using ffmpeg. By Using ffmpeg command I can find the difference between 2 videos. But i want to find the percentage different in 2 videos. 
 From the below ffmpeg output how can i found the percentage difference in two videos. Which attribute denote the difference.?

```
TaskList: video:530kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.266679%
TaskList: [libx264 @ 0000000002750b00] frame I:2     Avg QP:23.92  size: 29796
TaskList: [libx264 @ 0000000002750b00] frame P:97    Avg QP:22.97  size:  4477
TaskList: [libx264 @ 0000000002750b00] frame B:9     Avg QP:28.16  size:  5338
TaskList: [libx264 @ 0000000002750b00] consecutive B-frames: 83.3% 16.7%  0.0%  0.0%
TaskList: [libx264 @ 0000000002750b00] mb I  I16..4: 25.7% 37.8% 36.5%
TaskList: [libx264 @ 0000000002750b00] mb P  I16..4:  1.9%  4.5%  1.0%  P16..4: 26.7%  8.8%  3.8%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:53.3%
TaskList: [libx264 @ 0000000002750b00] mb B  I16..4:  0.7%  2.4%  2.7%  B16..8: 19.9%  8.8%  2.6%  direct: 4.7%  skip:58.2%  L0:32.3% L1:53.2% BI:14.4%
TaskList: [libx264 @ 0000000002750b00] 8x8 transform intra:55.1% inter:69.5%
TaskList: [libx264 @ 0000000002750b00] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 55.6% 70.0% 24.2% inter: 19.8% 26.7% 2.5%
TaskList: [libx264 @ 0000000002750b00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 25% 44%  5% 27%
TaskList: [libx264 @ 0000000002750b00] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 24% 26% 17%  5%  5%  6%  5%  6%  6%
TaskList: [libx264 @ 0000000002750b00] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 26% 29% 13%  5%  5%  6%  5%  6%  5%
TaskList: [libx264 @ 0000000002750b00] i8c dc,h,v,p: 44% 30% 20%  5%
TaskList: [libx264 @ 0000000002750b00] Weighted P-Frames: Y:6.2% UV:4.1%
TaskList: [libx264 @ 0000000002750b00] ref P L0: 64.2% 28.5%  5.8%  1.3%  0.1%
TaskList: [libx264 @ 0000000002750b00] ref B L0: 88.4% 11.6%
TaskList: [libx264 @ 0000000002750b00] kb/s:1204.25
```

Comment: That output is specific to the `x264` encoder. What do you mean by difference?

Comment: difference -> Between two videos.

Comment: what kind of difference: video specs, encoding parameters, quality, actual content? See the link in the answer listed in the comment above, it's too long to copy-paste.

Comment: Thank you very much. I want to find the difference in actual content.

Comment: Then I'm afraid the output won't help you as these are encoding stats. You probably need to implement your own algorithm to check for similarities.

Comment: There is any option for only find videos are non identical.

Comment: If you mean actually identical, including format etc, then a simple file comparison (i.e. ignoring the fact they are videos) should be fine. If you mean being able to check, even if the videos are in different formats and different bit rate etc then you probably need your own algorithm as aergistal says as there does not seem to be any obvious tool. There are tools which will allow you visually compare two side by side if that meets your needs.

Comment: Okay Mick thank you.